# log4net under sharepoint, missing the magic

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, log4net

I've spent all morning wading through a whole set of possibilities as to why log4net is not writing to file when setup under SharePoint 2010.

I've tried the separate log4net file route, but am currently trying it with it configured in the web.config.

I have updated trust to medium in web.config and the log4net dll is also in the GAC. When I breakpoint, my logger looks good with all logging enabled, however .Info() passes through with no error, but the log file is not created.

For luck I have given Everyone & the asp.net app pool runas user full control of the root log folder. Here's the config snippet and App_Start code:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
    ...

    <log4net>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
  </log4net>




    private static ILog logger; 

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ////This tells log4net where to go and look for its configuration file and also to watch it for any changes
      //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Config\Moogle\Log4Net.config"));

      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
          log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

          logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Moogle.Web");
          logger.Info("Application_Start Fired");
        });
    }
```

**Edit**
Having updated my config to the above (see my answer), i am still getting the log4net message:

```
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net: Logger: No appenders could be found for logger [Moogle.Web] repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Logger: Please initialize the log4net system properly.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done some digging, I've found a useful feature of log4net to ask it to do its own diagnostics.

You add the follwing app setting:

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

and the following section:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>
```

I am now able to see that its apparently the config that is wrong, as it is reporting:

```
log4net: XmlConfigurator: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using .config file section
log4net: XmlConfigurator: Application config file is [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\MOOGLEDEV0180\web.config]
log4net: XmlConfigurator: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net: Logger: No appenders could be found for logger [Moogle.Web] repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Logger: Please initialize the log4net system properly.
```

And all the time I was thinking it was permissions... so what's up with that config?

**Edit - working config**

Here's a stand alone log4net.config that does work (careful where you cut and paste from!)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollToFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs\Moogle\Moogle.Web.Log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <!-- Value of priority may be ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF -->
      <priority value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollToFile"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am aware log4net is great and much faster bu in SP2010 context I will highly recommend writing custom error messages to ULS ( now DB option is also there in SP2010 ).

Good sample 
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/search/label/SharePoint%20Diagnostic%20Service